# How do I add a LineSeries to a 100% stacked bar chart while my ColumnSeries stay stacked to 100% with amCharts?

Tags: amcharts4

I have several stacked column series displayed as "totalPercent".
For example:

```
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = "footfall";
    series.dataFields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";
    series.dataFields.dateX = "datetime";
```

[These display properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Qch.png)

I'm trying to add a line to my series' of stacked columns.
For example:

```
    var trend = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    trend.dataFields.valueY = "benchline";
    trend.dataFields.dateX = "datetime";
    trend.data = [  {"datetime": new Date(2021, 3, 23, 10),"benchline": 65}, 
                    {"datetime": new Date(2021, 3, 24, 13),"benchline": 65}, 
                    {"datetime": new Date(2021, 3, 26, 13),"benchline": 65}];
    trend.strokeWidth = 2
    trend.stroke = trend.fill = am4core.color("#c00");
    trend.legendSettings.labelText = "Demos benchmark";
```

The 'benchline' values get included in the total from which the 'totalPercent' is calculated for the stacked columns, [squashing the first 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY68y.png) (same number as I have points in my LineSeries).

Is there some way to include the LineSeries without distorting the columns?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iskanderblue/od692ksz/6/) with full code.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to add a second axis and attach the LineSeries to that axis.

```
    var valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis2.title.text = "Percent";
    valueAxis2.renderer.opposite = true;
    valueAxis2.min = 0;
    valueAxis2.max = 100;
    valueAxis2.strictMinMax = true;
    valueAxis2.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", function(text) {
      return text + "%";
    });

    var trend = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    trend.dataFields.valueY = "benchline";
    trend.dataFields.dateX = "datetime";
    trend.data = [  {"datetime": new Date(2021, 3, 23, 10),"benchline": 65}, 
                    {"datetime": new Date(2021, 3, 24, 13),"benchline": 65}, 
                    {"datetime": new Date(2021, 3, 26, 13),"benchline": 65}];
    trend.strokeWidth = 2
    trend.stroke = trend.fill = am4core.color("#c00");
    trend.legendSettings.labelText = "Demos benchmark";
    trend.yAxis = valueAxis2;
```